# Modificar uma entrada de um Form Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

Preciso aplicar nas saídas de formulários, feitos com Form, a função `title()`, para que todas as entradas de nomes e strings no banco sejam padronizadas. Fiz isso usando CSS `text-transform: capitalize;` mas somente na página é aplicado o efeito, quando o formulário é enviado para o banco as letras iniciais continuam minúsculas. Alguém sabe como modificar isso dentro da views?

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
...

def clean_zip_code(self):
    return self.cleaned_data['zip_code'].capitalize()
```

Comment: Saudações, eu enho que declarar essa função na minha views  ou no corpo da classe onde esta definido o formulário?

Comment: @FernandoMendes no forms.py